# Java Best Practice regarding clearing a Linked List

Tags: java, collections, garbage-collection, java-8

I am coding a data structure  Linked list in java(For my learning sake I am not using any standard java libraries) and I want to clear the data structure via null out the references. Please suggest me which approach is better

1) Just null the start reference of the list and that will suffice.

2) Apart from nulling out the start , I de-reference all next pointers of all internal nodes to null.Does this help the garbage collector in any way?

The confusion in I see approach 2 is followed in JDK for LinkedList implementation.But i don't see the same for TreeMap

I am using JDK 8

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.clear%28%29

Comment: Both will work. (2) will affect real-time behavior, might cost time. The point of (2) is that especially a double linked list of length N might need N garbage steps, but one gc can do multiple steps. Depends on the gc algorithm used. But as **missing reachability** is the main requirement for gc, I would not concern myself with that. Real time behaviour is much more important.

Comment: If you are data structure is similar to Java's LinkedList implementation, then I don't think either of the two approaches will be OK. The second one would be better because the generational GC can do a better job.

Comment: The main difference between `LinkedList` and `TreeMap` is that the latter has a relevance for real life code. If you are ever concerned about performance, you won’t use `LinkedList`. So when `LinkedList` wastes CPU cycles to “help the garbage collector”, it doesn’t matter…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and the answer has a long history with subtle tradeoffs.

The short answer is, clearing the references is not necessary for the correct operation of the data structure. Since you're learning data structures, I'd suggest that you not worry about this issue in your own implementation. My hunch (though I haven't benchmarked this) is that any benefit that might accrue from clearing all the link nodes will rarely be noticeable under typical conditions.

(In addition, it's likely that under typical conditions, `LinkedList` will be outperformed by `ArrayList` or `ArrayDeque`. There **are** benchmarks that illustrate this. It's not too difficult to come up with workloads where `LinkedList` outperforms the others, but it's rarer than people think.)

I was quite surprised to learn that the `clear` operation of `LinkedList` unlinks all the nodes from each other and from the contained element. Here's a link to the [code in JDK 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/jdk8-b132/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l444). This change dates back to 2003, and the change appeared in JDK 5. This change was tracked by the bug [JDK-4863813](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4863813). That change (or a slightly earlier one) clears the next and previous references from individual nodes when they're unlinked from the list. There's also a test case in that bug report that's of some interest.

The problem seems to be that it is possible to make changes to the `LinkedList`, which creates garbage nodes, faster than the garbage collector can reclaim them. This eventually causes the JVM to run out of memory. The fact that the garbage nodes are all linked together also seems to have the effect of impeding the garbage collector, making it easier for the mutator threads to outstrip the collector threads. (It's not clear to me how important it is to have multiple threads mutating the list. In the test case they all synchronize on the list, so there's no actual parallelism.) The change to `LinkedList` to unlink the nodes from each other makes it easier for the collector to do its work, and so apparently makes the test no longer run out of memory.

Fast forward to 2009, when the `LinkedList` code was given a "facelift." This was tracked by bug [JDK-6897553](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6897553) and discussed in this [email review thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2009-November/003135.html). One of the original motivations for the "facelift" was to reduce the `clear()` operation from O(n) to O(1), as unlinking all the nodes seemed unnecessary to that bug's submitter. (It certainly seemed unnecessary to me!) But after some discussion, it was decided that the unlinking behavior provided enough benefit to the garbage collector to retain it and to document it.

The comment also says that unlinking the nodes

> is sure to free memory even if there is a reachable Iterator

This refers to a somewhat pathological case like the following:

```
// fields in some class
List<Obj> list = createAndPopulateALinkedList();
Iterator<Object> iterator;

void someMethod() {
    iterator = list.iterator();
    // ...
    list.clear();
}
```

The iterator points to one of the linked list's nodes. Even though the list has been cleared, the iterator still keeps a node alive, and since that node has next and previous references, all of the nodes formerly in the list are still alive. Unlinking all the nodes in `clear()` lets these be collected. I think this is pretty pathological, though, since it's rare for an iterator to be stored in a field. Usually iterators are created, used, and discarded within a single method, most often within a single `for` loop.

Now, regarding `TreeMap`. I don't think there's a fundamental reason why `LinkedList` unlinks its nodes whereas `TreeMap` does not. One might like to think that the entire JDK code base is maintained consistently, so that if it's good practice for `LinkedList` to unlink its nodes, this also ought to have been done to `TreeMap`. Alas, this is not the case. Most likely what happened is that a customer ran into the pathological behavior with `LinkedList` and the change was made there, but nobody has ever observed similar behavior with `TreeMap`. Thus there was no impetus to update `TreeMap`.

Comment: Thanks @Stuart for the clear,specific and unequivocal answer.Feels great to know about the language history and the discussions that went through via mail chains.

Comment: Its great to know ArrayDeque outperforms LinkedList under typical conditions, considering the fact ArrayDeque is my favourite class :)